# If exists, duplicate row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, copy, exists, duplicate-data

In MSSQL it was working;

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE id=X) 
    BEGIN INSERT INTO T1(C1, C2, C3) 
       (SELECT C1, C2, 'Different Value' AS C3 FROM T1 WHERE id=X) 
    END
```

What is the counterpart syntax for MYSQL.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
INSERT INTO T1(C1, C2, C3) 
SELECT C1, C2, 'Different Value' AS C3 
FROM T1 
WHERE id=X
```

If a record id=X exists, it will be inserted, otherwise not.

Comment: Shouln't we use the keyword `values` !?

Comment: @Reza Nope, [`VALUES` is not required when getting the values FROM a `SELECT`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e885/1).

Comment: No, refer to documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html look for `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, values is used in `INSERT ... VALUES` version.